# Interpolation of the row and column operator spaces

Tags: operator-spaces, interpolation-spaces

If $R$ and $C$ are respectively the row and column operator spaces, and $\theta \in (0, 1)$, we denote by $R(\theta)$ the interpolation operator space $(R, C)_{\theta}$ (with $R(0) = R$ and $R(1) = C$).

It is true that if $0 \leq \theta_1 \neq \theta_2 \leq 1$, then $R(\theta_1)$ and $R(\theta_2)$ are not completely isomorphic.

I have a sense that this should be true, but I can't get a simple explanation of why.

On page 83 of Pisier's *The Operator Hilbert Space $OH$, Complex Interpolation and Tensor Norms* it is said:

'It is rather clear that [...] $R(\theta_1)$ and $R(\theta_2)$ are not completely isomorphic, in any case this will follow immediately from the next statement.'

Then he proceeds to describe explictly the operator norm on $R(\theta)$. But, as he said, it should be 'rather clear' that these spaces are not completely isomorphic. Is there a more direct argument to why this is the case?

More generally, is the same true if we have two not completely isomorphic quantizations of the same (infinite dimensional) Banach space on the ends of the interpolation scale?

Thank you